# Archive manager which has integration into Nemo except File Roller (Archive Manager)?

Tags: software-recommendation, plugins, archive, extension, nemo

I mean something like "Extract Here" and "Compress..." menus on right-click.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, Nemo can be integrated with the default archive manager shipped with Unity. [Webup8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) provides Nemo with a series of extensions that integrates it tightly with Unity. The steps are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
sudo apt-get install nemo-compare nemo-dropbox nemo-media-columns nemo-pastebin nemo-seahorse nemo-share nemo-emblems nemo-image-converter nemo-rabbitvcs
```

After this, among many other improvements, you should have the "Extract Here" and "Compress..." options in the context menu.

Comment: https://imgur.com/RW46TKW